# google map circle not binding to all markers in a array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The circle is only set to the last marker in my array, How would i set the circle to bind to all my makers.

And is it possible to have the circle to show a alert if a user maker enters the radius of the circle via the `getBounds()` method? because i have geolocation added to my code that tracks users location and once they enter the radius it needs to display a alert message.

```
var marker_school, ss;

    for (ss = 0; ss < location_school2.length; ss++) {

    marker_school = new google.maps.Marker({ 

         position: new google.maps.LatLng(location_school2[ss][1], location_school2[ss][2]),
         map: map, icon: school, animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE, visible: false,


    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker_school, 'click', (function(marker_school, ss) {
         return function() {
             $("#school_bg").show();
             $("#name_school").append(location_school2[ss][3]);

         }
    })(marker_school, ss));
    markers2.push(marker_school);

}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
     var currentZoom = map.getZoom();
    // iterate over markers and call setVisible
    if (currentZoom >= 14 && currentZoom <= 17) {
       for (ss = 0; ss < location_school2.length; ss++) {
        markers2[ss].setVisible(true);

       }
   }else if (currentZoom >= 8 && currentZoom <= 14) 
     {for (ss = 0; ss < location_school2.length; ss++) {
        markers2[ss].setVisible(false);

       }}
}); 

var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
  map: map,
  radius: 500,    // 10 miles in metres
  fillColor: '#AA0000', 
  strokeColor: '#FFF', strokeWeight: 0,
});
circle.bindTo('center', marker_school, 'position');
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  If you want to bind the circle to all the markers, you have to create a circle for each marker and bind each circle to its own marker (inside the loop).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the circle to all the markers, you have to create a circle for each marker and bind each circle to its own marker (inside the loop).  Note that 500 meters is no where near 5 miles.

```
for (ss = 0; ss < location_school2.length; ss++) {

  var marker_school = new google.maps.Marker({ 
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(location_school2[ss][1], location_school2[ss][2]),
     map: map, icon: school, animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE, visible: false,
  });
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
     map: map,
     radius: 500,    // 10 miles in metres
     fillColor: '#AA0000', 
     strokeColor: '#FFF', strokeWeight: 0,
  });
  circle.bindTo('center', marker_school, 'position'); 

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker_school, 'click', (function(marker_school, ss) {
     return function() {
         $("#school_bg").show();
         $("#name_school").append(location_school2[ss][3]);

     }
  })(marker_school, ss));
  markers2.push(marker_school);
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/4xw8wxtt/2/)